# jquery search id inside

Tags: jquery

I have a site develop in jquery. I want to select all id that contains a certian string for example:

```
<div id="home_test_div">
</div>
<span id"agency_test_span">test</span>
```

I want search all elements that contains inside its id the string `test`.
I know how to search an id that start with a certain string or finish with a certain string but inside? I never done this before.
I try with that code:

```
var search = "test";
$("[id$='"+search+"']").each(function(index) {
  //some code
}
```

Comment: Bookmark this page: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`attribute contains`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector:

```
$("[id*='"+search+"']").each(function(index) {
  //some code
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("[id*='"+search+"']").each(function(index) {
```

You are trying to find the selector whose id ends with **text** . But I don't see any id end with **test** in your case..

So try replacing with a `*`  which searches for the selector that contains `test` instead